# Rails Console - Find where created at = certain day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, rails-console

With Ruby on Rails console, is it possible to query the database for all records created on a certain day?

something like

```
date = "january 5 2013"
users = User.find(:all, :conditions => {:created_at => date})
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
date = Date.parse('january 5 2013')
users = User.where(created_at: date.midnight..date.end_of_day)
```

Comment: Anything wrong with using

date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day

?

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
User.where("Date(updated_at) = ?", "2018-02-9")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like

```
User.where("created_at::date = ?", "january 5 2013".to_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible like:

```
date = Date.parse("january 5 2013")
users = User.where(created_at: date)
```

but `created_at` is type of date-time like `2014-01-28 08:35:00.9608`

and I think All user have different created_at

So you may used like this

```
User.where("created_at = ?", "2014-01-23 16:19:48.199086")
```

Comment: The first part does not work. Don't you have to convert strings to date? The second part might work, but I need it to be variable. I want all users from that day, not a specific user.

Comment: You may use stamp gem and use varibale like
 date = Date.today.stamp("january 5 2013")

Answer (score 1):

If you see the follow link [Don't use BETWEEN (especially with timestamps)](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29)

You will note that you can have problems.

Instead you can use

```
users = User.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <=?', date.midnight, date.end_of_day)



"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE (created_at >= '2018-05-17 07:00:00' and created_at <='2018-05-18 06:59:59.999999')"
```