# Retrieve all records create on a particular date with the "where" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I use the "created_at" field to retrieve all records created on particular date. I specifically want to use the "where" method because I am querying other fields too.

The format of the date input provided by the user is 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails ActiveRecord date between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I want. The format of the date input provided by the user is 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: Here a similar question for you to take a look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410149/rails-console-find-where-created-at-certain-day

Comment: That works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found help. However, your question was premature. Describing a framework method should be the job of that framework's documentation, not stackoverflow. Please revisit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Stackoverflow is for people to ask questions about programming. This is indeed where the question should be asked whether it's about the Rails framework or about a code issue.